# Visual Studio Code - Criar vários arquivos ao mesmo tempo

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

existe alguma maneira de criar multiplos arquivos no visual studio code? por exemplo;

em new file, se eu digitar   `Navbar/index.js` ele cria a pasta `Navbar` com o arquivo `index.js`,

teria alguma sintaxe como, `NavBar/{index.js, styles.css}`

para criar os dois arquivos ou mais simultaneamente sem necessidade plugins?

Comment: Cara tem uma extensão muito levinha e simples de usar que vai te ajudar, da uma olhada na resposta que deixei mais detalhes e fiz um exemplo simples de como usar... é tão útil e fácil que eu mesmo estou usando agora rss

Answer (score 1):

Como vc pode ver nesse *issue* do projeto no GitHub ainda não existe nativamente essa opção no VS Code https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/310

**MAS......** exitem uma extensão que vc consegue fazer isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Primeiro vc instala a extensão
- Depois de instalada vc da um `ctrl+shift+p` e clica em "Create File" ou "Create Folder"
- Agora vc pode criar seus arquivos, ex: `/path/subpath/file1.js > file2.css > file3.html`

Link da extensão: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.create-file-folder